# Any NIO framework in C++

Tags: c++, nio

I want to use a NIO framework in C++ that can handle at least 100,000 concurrent connections.  I was thinking of using boost::asio, but I don't know if it scales very well on a multicore systems. Does somebody has experiences  with boost:asio and such a number of connections to handle?

Answer (score 5):

Boost ASIO will probably handle 10K connection on a modern hardware, but when it comes to performance, it is a waste of both CPU and memory resources. Below are some alternatives:

- [libevent](http://libevent.org)
- [libev](http://software.schmorp.de/pkg/libev.html)
- [epoll](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/epoll.4.html) (Linux Specific)
- [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) (FreeBSD, OS X specific)

I personally recommend you to go with [libevent](http://libevent.org) due to its portability and relatively high-performance.